# Python OOP shopping cart

Tags: python, beginner, object-oriented, e-commerce

I completed the following task:

> You need to create the foundations of an e-commerce engine for a B2C (business-to-consumer) retailer. You need to have a class for a customer
>   called User, a class for items in inventory called Item, and a shopping cart class calledCart. Items go in Carts, and Users can have multiple Carts. Also, multiple items can go into Carts, including more than one of any single item.

I am a new Pythoner, and don't have good knowledge of OOP. I feel the code is not good. I welcome recommendations to improve the code.Here's my code:

```
class Item(object):
    def __init__(self,itemname,itemprice):
        self.__itemname = itemname
        self.__itemprice = itemprice

    def GetItemName(self):
        return self.__itemname

    def GetItemPrice(self):
        return self.__itemprice

    def ChangeItemPrice(self,newprcie):
        self.__itemprice = newprcie

class Cart(dict):      #cart dict format:  {itemname:[price,number]}
    def ShowCart(self):
        return self   

class User(object):
    def __init__(self, name):    
        self.name = name
        self.__cartlist = {}
        self.__cartlist[0] = Cart()

    def AddCart(self):
        self.__cartlist[len(self.__cartlist)] = Cart()

    def GetCart(self, cartindex = 0):
        return self.__cartlist[cartindex]

    def BuyItem(self, item, itemnum, cartindex = 0):
        try:
            self.__cartlist[cartindex][item.GetItemName()][1] += itemnum
        except:
            self.__cartlist[cartindex].update({item.GetItemName():[item.GetItemPrice(),itemnum]})

    def BuyCancle(self, itemname, itemnum, cartindex = 0):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__': 

    item1 = Item('apple', 7.8)
    item2 = Item('pear', 5)   

    user1 = User('John')

    user1.BuyItem(item1, 5)
    print("user1 cart0 have: %s" % user1.GetCart(0).ShowCart())

    user1.BuyItem(item2, 6)
    print("user1 cart0 have: %s" % user1.GetCart(0).ShowCart())


    user1.AddCart()
    user1.BuyItem(item1, 5, 1)
    print("user1 cart1 have: %s" % user1.GetCart(1).ShowCart())
```

Comment: Was this brief specifically for Python or did you get to choose your own language?

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan   I have chosen Python.

Comment: To do this in the most "Pythonic" way would probably involve at least one if not of these not being classes you created, so it is a bit odd to review. Python doesn't lean as heavily on OOP as Java does but I hope the answers are helpful to you regardless.

Answer (score 2):

I have some notes on how you structured this, note that some are a bit Python specific.

Your attribute names should not have the class name in them. It's redundant because you'll always be accessing them from something else, ie. `Item.name` is simpler than `Item.itemname`. Also you shouldn't use double underscores to prefix the name. A Pythonic style is to use a *single* underscore to denote an attribute that should be treated as private and not directly accessed. But very often it's Python style to leave out any concept of setters and getters, instead just access them directly. Like this:

```
>>> apple = Item('apple', 7.8)
>>> print apple.name
apple
>>> apple.price = 7
>>> print apple.price
7
```

You could almost not have `Item` be a class, but your spec seems to require it so I wont suggest you change that.

Also you misspelled `newitemprice` as `newitemprcie`. You managed to make it consistent between the two (by copy pasting I assume) but keep an eye on little errors like that. They'll only cause headaches.

Your `Cart` is a little underdeveloped. All it does is subclass `dict` and then return itself when `ShowCart` is called? This is redundant since the `Cart` itself could be passed to places it's needed.

You mentioned in a comment you want to be able to do `Cart['apple']` to get the count of apples, but an easier way to do that is to just have an attribute of cart that's a dictionary. For example:

```
class Cart:
    def __init__(self, items):
        self.items = items

Cart({"apple": 5, "pear": 7})
Cart.items["apple"]
```

This is a much clearer way to get at the items without needing to inherent a dictionary into the `Cart` itself.

Maybe the cart could more directly manage items so you could have useful features like counting how many of each item is there. As it stands, you don't do anything special with a cart that has multiple instances of the same item. Why not keep track of that so you could easier print to the user what they have, rather than expecting them to just read a list of items.

While we're on it. Why not implement a method or two to print the contents of a `Cart` nicer? Maybe the `Cart` should be where the user actually purchases things? You need to think about what a cart does, and create those functions.

Why make `cartlist` a dictionary? You should make it a list instead. You can still do `cartlist.remove(cart_to_remove)`. Also don't name it `cartlist` *especially* if it's not a list, `carts` is better. Types don't need to be in names unless it's hard to tell what type a variable is.

Comment: thank you very much for your professional advice, and i will improve the code.

Comment: @burcepan Glad to help. Please do ask if any part is confusing as I'm not sure how much I should explain when you're a beginner and a lot of this answer is conceptual.

Comment: @ SuperBiasedMan :I have learned your advise,thanks again. and your question"Why make cartlist a dictionary?",because I want use the following feature of dictionary.   dict[key]  can get the value of the key.  for example,there is of dictionary {'apple':5, 'pear',6}, if i want to know the amount of the apple, i can use dict[apple] to achieve it. but if i use list , i must  iterate the list to find apple

Comment: @burcepan I see the confusion now. I edited my answer to explain how to use an attribute of `Cart` instead of making it inherit from `dict`.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan Don't sub-class to extend functionality, instead make the parent a variable?
That doesn't sound like OOP.
Why should you inherit `dict` to then hold a different `dict`,
why not just use `self`?
When you want to extend functionality you will have to always use `self.items` rather than `self`.
And finally `Cart['a'] = 'a'` is valid with your cart class, but will never be used by the class.

Comment: @JoeWallis Oops, I copied that code and forgot to remove the inheritance part. That's removed now.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create a specialized implementation of a dictionary, as you've done here:

```
class Cart(dict):      #cart dict format:  {itemname:[price,number]}
    def ShowCart(self):
        return self
```

This, literally does, nothing. The method `ShowCart` essentially just returns the dictionary, and again, is useless. The only thing this class accomplishes is making the code harder to read, and harder to maintain.

You also have a few minor [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) violations. In case you didn't know, PEP8 is Python's official style guide.

- Functions should be named in `snake_case`.
- There should be two blank lines between top-level code/functions/classes, not one.

Other than that, there's not too much that I can find wrong with this.

Comment: Ethan Bierlein:thank you very much, I have learned PEP8 after you tell me this document. I  do find some PEP8 violations. tanks again.

Answer (score 1):

## Main

First, before I talk about the OOP parts, I'll look at you main.
And say everything that could be classed as 'wrong'.

It's really good that you used `if __name__ == '__main__'`.
It normally is really small, such as a single function call,
sometimes with a setup for the framework you are using.

Keep your apostrophes consistent. Either `'` or `"`.
The exception to that is when one is inside the other.

You should use `str.format`, it's better than the old `%`.
And allows for more functionality.

```
print('user1 cart0 have: {}'.format(user1.GetCart(0).ShowCart()))
```

---

## Classes

First, Python has no 'private' variables.
`_variable` is normally used as private,
as developers should trust each other.
Whereas `__variable` uses name mangling.
No, it's still not private.

Below shows how both work:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 'a'
        self._b = 'b'
        self.__c = 'c'

my_class = MyClass()
print my_class.a
# a
print my_class._b
# b
print my_class._MyClass__c
# c
```

It's normally recommended to only use `_variable`,
as some people have a large dislike for name mangling.

---

It seems like you come from a Java/getter-setter background.
Python can do that, but don't.

Python is happy that it has no privates.

> For simple public data attributes, it is best to expose just the attribute name, without complicated accessor/mutator methods.

- [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#designing-for-inheritance)

And so I would say that most of your code for `Item` in bad.
And so would change it to be simpler.

```
class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, name, price):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
```

Now we can just change things with ease,
and use operators such as `+=`.

---

Personally I think `Cart` is useless at the moment.
And I would put `BuyItem`'s logic in here.

---

You should change `__cartlist` to a list.
`self.__cartlist = [Cart()]`.

You should change `AddCart` to use the new list. `self.__cartlist.append(Cart())`

Again `GetCart`, why can't we just have `__cartlist` public?
This will remove `GetCart`, and will make it more Pythonic.

Now time for `BuyCart`.

- You yourself didn't use `GetCart`.
  Shows how much people would love to use it, if given the option.
- Your `try` is massive.
- Your `except` is hard to read, and is to long.
- I think `amount` is better than `itemnum`.

And so you should store `self.__cartlist[cartindex]` in a variable.
Then you can use it in both `try` and `except` with ease.

```
cart = self.__cartlist[cartindex]
try:
    cart[item.GetItemName()][1] += itemnum
except:
    cart.update({item.GetItemName():[item.GetItemPrice(),itemnum]})
    
# If you made it more Pythonic

cart = self.cart_list[cart_index]
try:
    cart[item.name][1] += amount
except:
    cart.update({
        item.name: [item.price, amount]
    })
```

The first one removes a bug, and shows that this should be implemented on `Cart` instead.
The second half shows how following Python's philosophy just makes it easier to read.

This is how I would implement your code:

```
class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, name, price):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price

class Cart(dict):
    def add_item(self, item, amount):
        try:
            self[item.name][1] += amount
        except IndexError:
            self.update({
                item.name: [item.price, amount]
            })

class User(object):
    def __init__(self, name):    
        self.name = name
        self.carts = [Cart()]

    def add_cart(self):
        self.carts.append(Cart())
        
    def add_item(self, item, amount, cart_index=0):
        self.carts[cart_index].add_item(item, amount)

def main():
    apple = Item('apple', 7.8)
    
    john = User('John')

    # I would choose `john.add_item(apple, 5, 1)`
    # or `john.carts[0].add_item(apple, 5)`
    # Not both.
    john.add_item(apple, 5)
    print("John's first cart has: {}".format(john.carts[0]))

    john.carts[0].add_item(Item('pear', 5), 6)
    print("John's first cart has: {}".format(john.carts[0]))
    
    john.add_cart()
    john.add_item(apple, 5, 1)
    print("John's second cart has: {}".format(john.carts[1]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

As you can probably guess, Python's OOP is much friendlier.
If you have to have getters, setters and non-sense, then you didn't pick the right language.

Comment: thank you very much, and i need some time to Io understand your advice。

Comment: To elaborate: if you ever develop the need to intercept the access to the instance variables, you can later change them to [properties](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property), and write getters and setters.